# Is there a relation between the characteristic roots and the s.e of the arima coefficients?

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, forecasting, arima, standard-error

in [Forecasting: Principles and Practice](https://otexts.com/fpp2/arima-r.html) there's a warning that

> inverse characteristic roots close to the unit circle may be numerically unstable, and the corresponding model will not be good for forecasting

Is this the only way to discover this instability? or are there other telltale signs such as the s.e. of the ar/ma terms being large, or the confint being large or including zero? or is there no relation?